# jCarousel unload / disable / remove

Tags: jquery, jcarousel

I am using jCarousel to have a carousel of images in my page. It works great and have no complaints, but I am using the tabbing on the page and when I goto another tab, it get an ugly jCarousel error. Basically what I want to do is to remove the jCarousel from my element when I goto a new tab but for the life of me can't figure it out

To add the carousel I am using code like this $("#myelement").jCarousel({ /* config params */});

But I am unsure of how to remove .jCarousel from $("#myelement") any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to PaDalton's answer, I also detached the resize event from the window as my carousel was inside a ([colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox)) popup box.

```
$(window).unbind('resize.jcarousel');
```

When the event got triggered, the `$(this).dimensions(e)` line sent the alert message as the li node didn't have a size, it thought the the object was to be displayed but without a size it would not be able to compute the carousel dimensions properly.

The error message was `Infinite Loop - no width or height set`

Answer (score 2):

Here is my way to remove the element and not get an error:

```
function mycarousel_initCallback(carousel){

$("#main_holder").mouseenter(function(){
    if(document.getElementById("event_scroller")){
        carousel.startAuto(2);
    }
}).mouseleave(function(){
    carousel.stopAuto();
});

$("#main_holder a").click(function(){
    carousel.stopAuto();
    carousel.remove();
});};

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#event_scroller").jcarousel({
    scroll: 1,
    wrap: 'circular',
    vertical: true,
    animation: 700,
    initCallback: mycarousel_initCallback
});
});
```

when we click on a link in the mainarea,
my jCarousel element will be removed from another script so
we have a handler for this witch is stopping the carousel and than .remove .

I've tried to do this outside the callback but it seams that the jCarousel
is only controllable from inside the callback.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution for this ugly js error "Jcarousel: No width/height set for items ...". Try to avoid double initialization of jCarousel.

```
var carousel_initialized = false;

if(!carousel_initialized) {
jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
    ... // all your parameters
    initCallback: function() {
        carousel_initialized = true;
    }
});
```

Or try to get an instance of jCarousel like

```
carousel_initialized = $("#mycarousel").data('jcarousel');
if(!carousel_initialized) {
    jQuery('#mycarousel').jcarousel({
        ... // all your parameters
    });
}
```

If you replace the jCarousel container via AJAX you should do something like this:

```
if( myCarousel = $("#mycarousel").data('jcarousel') ) {
    myCarousel.stopAuto()
    myCarousel.reset();
}
```

I hope this helps someone...

schulle7

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're talking about this plugin: http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/

What type of error are you getting? I'm guessing it's trying to find elements that aren't visible and failing. It'd seem like you could just bind a function to the tab switching to either hide the carousel or call its reset() method.

Comment: yes thats the JQuery-Plugin i'm meaning.
the error is:
jCarousel: No width/height set for items. This will cause an infinite loop. Aborting...
I cnow the reason why the error is coming but i have to remove the element and also the binding of the plugin to the element.
something like $("myelement").remove(jCarousel) ?!